# Is there a way to use the low level mongoDB backend from persistent-mongoDB?

Tags: haskell, yesod

In the SQL version of persistent it appears that direct access to SQL is done with `rawSql`. Is there a similar way to access low level commands from the mongoDB backend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB Example for Yesod / Persistent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731953/mongodb-example-for-yesod-persistent)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as the other question doesn't talk about using the direct API for MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out to be much easier than I thought. Just import `Database.MongoDB` and use the raw driver commands inside runDB. Example:

```
import Database.MongoDB
...
postCommentR :: DocumentId -> Handler Value
postCommentR documentId = do
  comment <- commentOr400
  let idString = toPathPiece documentId
      contents = commentBody comment
  runDB $ DB.modify (DB.select ["_id" DB.=: idString] "Document") ["$push" DB.=: ["comments" DB.=: contents]]
  returnJson $ object []
```